# IMPORTXML and XPATH to import numbers from Google search

Tags: xml, import, google-sheets

I've been working on this importxml for a few days and still struggling with XPATH. When doing a google search for a US "store name address" + the word "phone number" google shows on the right side the name, full address and phone number of the store.  I'd like to populate google sheet with this **phone number** of the store.

For example, cell A1 contains: *TD 5650 Yonge St North York phone number*

IMPORTXML will look for A1 in google

Here is a classical div class, the class *_XWk* seems unique within the XML code.

```
    <div class="_XWk">
      <a class="fl r-igV1NyyD90oU" href="#" data-number="+14162505855" data-pstn-out-call-url="" title="Call via Hangouts" jsaction="r.oVdbr2mIpA8" data-rtid="igV1NyyD90oU" jsl="$t t-6xg4lalHw8M;$x 0;" data-ved="0ahUKEwjE_7yc8s7ZAhUFbawKHcYSAF8QkAgIKygAMAA">(416) 250-5855</a>
</div>
```

A kind user here mentioned that I should try this XPATH on **Call via Hangouts**, which returns again #NA and the error message says error in parsing.

I mixed REGEXEXTRACT and IMPORTXML to obtain the number from the span class though technically I wouldn't need regexextract.. IMPORTXML alone returns #N/A, and so does REGEXEXTRACT.

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q="&A1,"//a[@title="Call via Hangouts"]/@href"), "[0-9]+")
```

The XPATH looks good to me, I don't understand why it doesn't return the phone number. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is IMPORTXML returning what you expect? Also, your xpath is returning href which is actually '#' but you expect an integer.

Comment: It doesn't return anything, just an error message. Should it be @data-number?

Comment: Should be the value itself I guess `"//a[@title="Call via Hangouts"]/text()"`. I would get the value first without the regexp part. Once you get the expected value go for the regexp extract.

Comment: Thank Luis, I really like your method. I tried that and still didn't work. It returns some #N/A errors saying there is an issue with parsing. It works well with Yellow Pages, but somehow I am not able to extract info from Google..

Comment: Some post mention problems with dynamic pages, that could be a hint too.

Comment: Thank you Luis, I'll look into that!